# Air handler and condenser wet dog smell. Insulation replacement?

Tags: hvac, insulation

My furnace is in up flow position - that is, return trunk and air handler on the bottom, gas furnace in the middle, and A/C condenser coils above, blowing into the supply trunk.

Unfortunately I experienced some water pooling issues inside the condenser not long ago [1]. I've rectified that and sprayed the coils and insulation inside the condenser unit, and the insulation inside the air handler with various things to kill mold.

Nothing seems to work - the "wet dog" smell remains, and gets blown through the house. I hired someone to examine it, who declared he could not smell it and since he didn't see any standing water (as I fixed that!), the wet dog smell was probably from... my dog. He suggested that maybe the underside of the condenser coils was covered in fur. He charged his fee and left. I got a look inside the condenser coil and lo and behold, no fur.

This is a long winded way of asking: is it OK/sane to replace the insulation inside the air handler and condenser unit with closed cell foam insulation? I am not advocating a specific product or anything, but [this is the kind of thing I have in mind](https://www.reflectixinc.com/applications/diy/duct-insulation-r-6/).

The insulation would, of course, be on the inside of the units. It supports a temperature range of -30°F to 180°F. I would explicitly NOT be screwing with the furnace insulation.

Comment: Is it a furnace? There's a heat exchanger above the blower. Pull the blower out (good times) and shop vac it out with the fuzzy stick. There's duct insulation inside? That cannot be ruled out, and honestly its just for noise only. Pull that too. Also, there's water pooling at the *coil*, inside, not outside (condenser) right? It's level, yes? and the drain is clean? and there's an open tee at the top letting air out so it can *actually* drain, right?

Comment: Mop your basement floor with bleach.

Comment: @Mazura there was water pooling in the condenser (in the drain pain), because it was not level. It appears to have poured over the side a little bit at times. I fixed the level and drain setup, and it is now draining well - there is an open T top of the drain line, and it's all clean. There is insulation inside both the blower and the condenser - it looks like foil faced fiberglass in the condenser, and either fiberglass or rock wool in the blower.

Comment: Foil faced is prob fine, it's that rock wool. Also, that's *the coil*. Water pooling in the condenser outside doesn't matter. - "He suggested that maybe the underside of the [coil] was covered in fur. [He then opened up the thing and cleaned it. *Then*] He charged his fee and left." ? - "I fixed the level and drain setup" : Run the AC for two weeks... Now how is it?

Comment: * do *nothing* and then run the AC for 2 weeks.... You have a dog and your house is wet; it's going to smell like dog. Stop getting it wet and it should... abate.

Comment: And... stop calling AC techs that call coils condensers. ;)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify that it's been a month or so since fixing the coil level. The tech did not open it up or clean it - I did that. There was no dog fur present. The dog, FWIW, does not smell. The interior of the blower does.

Comment: Eh, we're already past that stage.... Well, pull what you can and spray the rest with some kind of pet odor stuff? "I cleaned it" - with a garden hose? No, seriously.... It'll make a total mess and smell for another two weeks, but it might actually do something.... Maybe clean the fuzz off the squirrel cage?

Comment: I cleaned the coil itself with coil cleaner. I sprayed the insulation looking bits with mold killer.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion - pretend I said coil everywhere I said condenser.